# RxJava Scheduler to observe on main thread

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

If I write something like this, then **both** the operation and notification will be on the **current** thread...

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Do Something")
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If I do the operation on a background thread like this, then **both** the operation and notification will be on a **background** thread...

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Do Something")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If I want to observe on the main thread and do in the background in **Android** I would do...

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Do Something")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

But If I was writing a standard Java program, what is the equivalent to state that you want to observe on the main thread?

Comment: You need a blocking scheduler for this as Java main thread is not a pool/looper. This is only available for RxJava 2.x in the extensions project: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#blockingscheduler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the `Observable` to a `BlockingObservable` via `.toBlocking()`; this gives you blocking methods to wait for completion, get one item, etc.

Answer (score 16):

For RxJava2 use "`blockingSubscribe()`"

```
Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .blockingSubscribe(integer -> {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                });
```